# Php update and subtract array values based on request value

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, foreach

I'm trying to write a script that subract the order value to multiple warehouse location depends on order quantity and availablity of item in each warehouse.

Order Table :

```
item_id | quantity |
   1         50
```

Warehouse Table :

```
item_id | available |
   1         50
   1         20
```

Real Problems :

- Avalability of item in warehouse turns 0 if the order value = availability of items.
- loop will break if there's no available item in warehouse.
- Update inventory value based on difference between availablity of items and order value.

MY PHP CODE :

```
foreach($warehouse->stocks as $stock) {
    if($order->quantity <= $stock->available || $order->quantity === 0) {
        $stock->available = $stock->available - $order->quantity;
        break;
    }

    $stock->available = $stock->available - $order->quantity;
}
```

My example data and desired output:

```
$orderValue = 50; \\this will be the order value
$array      = array(50, 20); \\this will be the array inventory values

Output : 
$orderValue = 0;
$array      = array(0, 20);
----------------------------------
$orderValue = 50; \\this will be the order value
$array      = array(25, 20); \\this will be the array inventory values

Output : 
$orderValue = 5;
$array      = array(0, 0);
----------------------------------
$orderValue = 50; \\this will be the order value
$array      = array(52, 10); \\this will be the array inventory values

Output : 
$orderValue = 0;
$array      = array(2, 10);
----------------------------------
$orderValue = 50; \\this will be the order value
$array      = array(20, 25, 25); \\this will be the array inventory values

Output : 
$orderValue = 0;
$array      = array(0, 0, 20);
```

Comment: 1) I can't follow the logic of your desired output, please elaborate . 2) does the warehouse table holds the inventory for all warehouses or you have a separate table for each warehouse?

Comment: let's say that the $orderValue will subtracted to (array values) until the $orderValue turns to 0 or no available array value to be subtracted to $orderValue. as you can see in my output above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to separate the to scenarios when checking availability in the warehouses:

1. if the order is bigger than availbility.
2. if the order is less or equal than availability

   ```
     foreach ($warehouse->stocks as $stock)
        {
              //if order is bigger we "zeroing" warehouse and subtracting from order
              if($order->quantity> $stock->available ) 
              {
                 $order->quantity -=  $stock->available; 
                 $stock->available=0;
              }  
             else
             {
                //if order is less we "zeroing" order and subtracting from warehouse (and exiting cause we dont need to check more warehouses)
                $stock->available-=$order->quantity;
                $order->quantity =0;
                break;
             }
        }
   ```

Comment: I understand the code but. if I have 3 available items and 2 available items are equal to $requestValue the 3rd item value update to 0 too.

Comment: updated my code. if its equal you go to the else and break out from the loop (so you wont get to the other warehouses)

Comment: or if I have 2 items ($item1 = 45 and $item2 = 25), $requestValue = 50. $item2 turns to 0 instead of 20.

Comment: are you sure its the result after updating the code? (i changed >= to > from the if expression)

Comment: $variable -=5  shorthand for => $variable= $variable -5; see: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/operators.php ("combination arithmetic & assignment operators" section)